# Struct initialization with {} and ()

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, initialization

When I have a struct

```
   struct Point
    {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    }
```

Why it's possible to write

```
Point p = {10, 20, 30};
Point p0 {10, 20, 30};
auto p1 = Point{10, 20, 30};
```

Using {}. But I can't write with ()

```
Point p(10,10,10);
auto p1 = Point(10,10,10);
```

With error

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Point '
```

Comment: (...) Is the syntax-tool for a function call. In this case, it's a call to a constructor, but you have not defined a constructor! C++20 changed this and will make it compile (at the cost of even more complicated and confusing rules IMO).

Answer (score 0):

Since C++20 you can perform [aggregate-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) with parentheses initializer.

> ```
> T object (arg1, arg2, ...);   (5) (since C++20)
> ```

Before C++20, `Point p(10,10,10);` is supposed to call a constructor of `Point` taking 3 `int`s, but `Point` doesn't have such constructor. As you've showed you have to use braced initializer to perform aggregate-initialization, or provide such a constructor for `Point` then you could use both parentheses and braced initializer.

Comment: So in terms of creating an object {} and () are somehow different? So objects are created in some different ways?

Comment: @Display Yes, there're many different [initializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) in C++, they have different styles and effects.

Comment: @Display • There's even a good hour-long presentation on [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.